# TypeScript can't submit form

Tags: typescript

When is use typescript,vs tell me HTMLElment will don't have the submit property.

```
document.getElementById('case_form').submit();
```

How can i use `form.submit()` in the typescript file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to tell TypeScript that this element is in fact a `<form>`:

```
var myForm = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('case_form');
myForm.submit();
```

The main point here is `<newType>value`, which tells TypeScript to convert `value` to `newType`.